# cos^-1 in c++ wrong value

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to get the degrees for angle a in my program but i am getting answers that are in the thousands and not related to a triangle.
I cant seem to work it out.
am I using cos^-1 correctly

My formula is A=cos^(-1)⁡((b^2+c^2-a^2)/2bc)

This is my code so far.

```
// ConsoleApplication6.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "math.h"

/* enter three variables a, b ,c to create a triangle*/
int main()
{
    double a;               /*insert dimensions of side a*/
    double b;               /*insert dimensions of side b*/
    double c;               /*insert dimensions of side c*/
    double perimeter;       /*variable for the perimeter of a triangle*/
    double p;               /*variable for the semi perimeter of a triangle*/
    double s;               /*variable for the area of a triangle*/
    double PI = 3.14259;    /*Constant for PI*/
    double angleA;          /* Variable for angle A*/
    double angleB;          /* Variable for angle B*/
    double angleC;          /* Variable for angle C*/


    /* Get the user to enter the dimensions of a*/
    printf_s("enter the  dimensions of a: ");   
    scanf_s("%lf", &a);                         

    /* Get the user to enter the dimensions of b*/
    printf_s("enter the  dimensions of b: ");   
    scanf_s("%lf", &b);

    /* Get the user to enter the dimensions of c*/
    printf_s("enter the  dimensions of c: ");   
    scanf_s("%lf", &c);                          

    /* Conditions of a triangle*/
    if (a+b > c && a+c > b && b+c > a)

        printf_s("True\n");                    /* Display True if able to make a triangle*/

    else printf_s("False\n");                   /* Display false if unable to make a triangle*/


    /*output total perimeter*/
    perimeter = a + b + c;


    printf_s("The perimeter of the triangle is: %lf\n", perimeter);

    /*output total area*/
    p = (a + b + c) / 2;
    s = sqrt(p*(p - a)*(p - b)*(p - c));

    printf_s("The area of the triangle is: %lf\n", s);

    /*output angle A*/

    angleA = acos(-1)*(pow(b,2) + pow(c,2) - pow(a,2)) / 2 * a * b/180 * PI;

    printf_s("The angle of A is: %lf degrees\n", angleA);







    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Performance note: `b*b` will often be noticeably faster than `pow(b,2)`. As always, profile to be sure this is true for your platform and case.

Comment: @user4581301 pow() almost  always implemented through exponent, that would  be way slower   on practically every platform (and less accurate)

Answer (score 3):

Note that is  angle between  a and c sides (opposite to b )

[image]

You should write  formula for angle between b and c similar to this:

```
double  cosA = 0.5*( b / c + c / b  - a*a/(b*c));

//  short-circuit and sanitize argument of acos() here.. it must be -1...+1 range
//  but math rounding or wrong arguments (impossible triangle?) may cause 
// it to go outside that range.
double  angleA  = acos(cosA);
```

Note that result is in radians.

Answer (score 2):

this here:  **acos(-1)** look peculiar in your equation, you don't need the acos of -1 pi radians...

so 1st thing

> **cos(x)^(-1)** is the same as **1/cos(x)** or just **sec(x)**

you need to write this  **A=cos^(-1)⁡((b^2+c^2-a^2)/2bc)**  properly

if you mean the inverse function of **cos(x)** aka **acos(x)** then the argument -1 is not correct in your equation

your final equation must look like:

```
double  angleA  = acos(x);
```

where x have to be calculates ad:

```
(a*a + c*c -b*b)/(2*a*c)
```

## Edit:

What you are trying to do is calculate the information of a triangle by knowing the dimensions of the sides ([Heron's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula))

[image]

the angle between those sides is calculated by

[image]

so the 3 angles you need are:

```
angleAB = acos((a*a + b*b - c*c) / (2 * a * b));
std::cout << "The angle of A is: " << angleAB << " radians  " << std::endl;
std::cout << "or: " << angleAB * 180 / PI << " degrees  " << std::endl;

angleBC = acos((c*c + b*b - a*a) / (2 * c * b));
std::cout << "The angle of B is: " << angleBC << " radians  " << std::endl;
std::cout << "or: " << angleBC * 180 / PI << " degrees  " << std::endl;

angleCA = acos((c*c + a*a - b*b) / (2 * c * a));
std::cout << "The angle of B is: " << angleCA << " radians  " << std::endl;
std::cout << "or: " << angleCA * 180 / PI << " degrees  " << std::endl;
```

Comment: i have changed the equation to `angleA = ((b*b)+(c*c)-(a*a))/2*a*b;` but i am still getting an answer of 2468.803399 when i use the following sides
a = 15
b = 15
c = 20

i should get 45. when i do this on my calculator it works

Comment: @Elijah Ceeney no, no, no.. you both getting formula wrong

Comment: @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツ acos is reverse function, it does not take radians. what OP was confused  by is the really incorrect method of describing acos as cos^(-1)

Comment: @ΦXocę 웃 Пepeúpa ツacos isn't cos, it's arccos() , it's argument is supposed real result of cos(x)

Comment: @Swift I meant cos(x)(^-1) is the same as 1/cos(x) = sec(x) same radians argument : )

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ There was no  cos(x)(^-1) , there was cos^(-1)⁡ - "calculator style" designation of arcos. That is most calculators have cos() button and "-1" added if you press FUNC before it

Comment: @Elijah Ceeney see my answer

Comment: I have discovered that the equation is not the problem i took the angleA equation out and still received the same result so there must be a problem with my code

Comment: enter the  dimensions of a: 15
enter the  dimensions of b: 15
enter the  dimensions of c: 20
True
The perimeter of the triangle is: 50.000000
The area of the triangle is: 111.803399
The angle of A is: 2468.184414 degrees
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: This is the same answer doesnt matter what i do to the equation but if i change the variables of a, b and c i get a different answer.

Comment: @ElijahCeeney, you are calculating the angles wrong, see the update!

Comment: @Spektre, okie dokie, no problem... thansk anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer was

```
angleA = acos(((b*b) + (c*c) - (a*a)) / (2 * b*c)) * 180 / PI;

printf_s("The angle of A is: %lf degrees\n", angleA);

                /*output angle B*/

angleB = acos(((a*a) + (c*c) - (b*b)) / (2 * a*c)) * 180 / PI;

printf_s("The angle of B is: %lf degrees\n", angleB);

                /*output angle B*/

angleC = 180 - (angleA + angleB);

printf_s("The angle of C is: %lf degrees\n", angleC);

                /*output longest side*/
```

Comment: Would be fair to accept one of the other answers, which are both correct.